# How to do a ternary in element className

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, jsx, tailwind-css

I am creating a website using React and Next.js. In my website, I have a component called section.tsx that renders a subsection of an article using the given props.
I want the component to take in an 'align' property. I want to do a ternary operator in the className of a div element that checks if the align property is equal to 'right'. If it is true, it should set a tailwind css class to end, and if it is false it should set it to start.

Here's my code:

```
function Section({ idVal, text, title, align }) {
  return (
    <div
      id={idVal}
      className={`mt-12 w-full h-fit text-` + {align} + `grid place-items-` + {align == `right` ? `end` : `start`}}
    >
      <div className="text-4xl text-white text-end mt-20 mr-[15vw] border-b-[1px] border-b-slate-500 w-96 pl-5 rotate-2">
        <h2 className="mr-[4vw] -rotate-2">{title}</h2>
      </div>
      <p className="text-white w-[38vw] mr-[28vw] mt-8 whitespace-pre-line">
        {text}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Section;
```

However, the above code is throwing the following errors: `, expected` (on the ==), `Identifier expected`, and `Expression expected`.

Comment: Typo?  Did you mean to surround your expression with *parentheses* instead of *curly braces*?  Curly braces are denoting an object, and that's a syntax error for creating an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty close. Swap your `{}` for `()` to evaluate an expression.

In JSX, `{}` gives you the ability to jump into JavaScript to evaluate an expression. Once inside the `{}` it's just like writing normal JavaScript:

```
// Change
className={`mt-12 w-full h-fit text-` + {align} + `grid place-items-` + {align == `right` ? `end` : `start`}}

// To
className={`mt-12 w-full h-fit text-` + {align} + `grid place-items-` + (align == `right` ? `end` : `start`)}
```

Note sure what you intend to do the with `{align}` since that creates an object and then converts that object to a string when you concatenate it.

The way I would write it:

```
const alignClass = align === "right" ? "end" : "start";

className={`mt-12 w-full h-fit text-${alignClass} grid place-items-${alignClass}`}
```